# Typescript reducer not accepting type `string | null`

Tags: typescript, redux

I have a reducer. It has a field that can take either a `string` or `null`

I have an interface for the reducer

```
export interface ExpertFeedback {
  feedback: Feedback[],
  feedbackConversationMessages: Message[],
  feedbackConversation: string | null,
  // feedbackConversation: any,
}
```

Reducer with contents removed

```
const INITIAL_STATE: types.ExpertFeedback = {
  feedback: [],
  feedbackConversationMessages: [],
  feedbackConversation: null
};

const expertFeedback = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action: types.AppActions): types.ExpertFeedback =>
```

With type `any` it works fine. But if I put it as type `string | null` it throws this

```
Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

`any` seems sloppy. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Where specifically does the error show up?  Ideally you'd provide a [mcve] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE to demonstrate the problem, but [I don't see any error](https://tsplay.dev/Gm3BLN).

Answer (score 1):

```
Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

This error message is telling you that if you have something which can either be `string | null`, you can't use it in a place that's expecting a `string`.

So based on that, I'm assuming that somewhere down the line you are accessing the property `feedbackConversation` on an `ExpertFeedback` object and treating it as if it were a `string`.  In order to do that, you have to first verify that it's not `null`.

```
if ( state.feedbackConversation !== null ) {
  // ok to treat as a string
  state.feedbackConversation.toLowerCase();
  someStringFunction( state.feedbackConversation );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled `strictNullChecks` in `tsconfig` ?

Comment: Is that how I should do it? I guess it's not optional, it has to be there. It just has to be null or a string

Comment: In the `tsconfig`, have you enabled the `strictNullChecks` ?